# Pass by reference to COM object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Trying to pass `i` variable to `test` function that must change value:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Welcome to my site</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">

var atl = new ActiveXObject("ATL.Object.1");
var i =6;
atl.test(i);
document.write(i);

</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

But in output I still have `6`. How to pass value by reference?

Comment: Primitives are passed by value. Use objects instead. Or return the modified value back into `i`.

Comment: JavaScript only offers pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. There are ways to achieve similar effects (e.g. passing an object and mutating) it, but you cannot achieve real pass-by-reference.

Comment: You can't. You could pass it a object and muate it though.

Answer (score 0):

On Javascript pass by reference does not exist. You can use an object to pass and it works like passing by reference.

eg :

```
    var atl = new ActiveXObject("ATL.Object.1");
    var i = { value: 6};
//if ActiveXObject does not work with your Object, than you need to make an adapter or store the value back to i
    atl.test(i);
    document.write(i.value);
```